# JavaFX: LoadException resolving onAction for event handler of a button

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am new to JavaFX. Trying to follow a tutorial to generate a scene and associate eventhandler with a button.

I created a Main.FXML and edited in SceneBuilder. Since I added SceneBuilder's path in my IDE, it is able to detect my main controller. I wrote a function to generate random number.

```
public class MainController {

    public static void generateRandom(ActionEvent event) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int myrand = rand.nextInt(500) + 1;
        System.out.print(Integer.toString(myrand));
    }
}
```

In scenebuilder, it detects this method in controller which can be easily added as eventhandler for OnAction of the button. Main.FXML is updated after the operations.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="300" prefWidth="500" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" fx:controller="application.MainController">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="204.0" layoutY="204.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#generateRandom" text="Button" />
      <Label layoutX="138.0" layoutY="36.0" prefHeight="144.0" prefWidth="210.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

My main application class is as below:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setTitle("My Title");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

When I run the app, I got error:

> javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='#generateRandom',
>   either the event handler is not in the Namespace or  there is an error
>   in the script.
>   /C:/Users/Oscar/Workspace/Sunoco/bin/application/Main.fxml:10

[Error resolving “onAction” while loading FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505275/error-resolving-onaction-while-loading-fxml) suggests it may have to do with wrong import for `ActionEvent` which is not the case. Plus everything is set up automatically using SceneBuilder and Eclipse. So why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem will be solved if you use an `@FXML` annotation on the eventMethod. Besides, try not to make methods static in the controller, as it may be confusing/misleading. If you need that method to be accesible from elsewhere, consider declaring it in a separate (utility like) class.

Comment: Looks like `static` is causing problem. After I took it out it worked without `@FXML` annotation.

Comment: I used skeletal constructor code from SceneBuilder. This had "internal" functions, so the .jfx file couldn't find these functions.