# Make IntelliJ prefer one class over another in imports or mark the other as error

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm working in an old application that's been written in Swing, and I'm moving it to JavaFX. Because of that I have a misfortune of having many classes that have the same names, but are from different packages. For example:

```
javafx.event.ActionEvent
java.awt.event.ActionEvent
```

On more then one occasion I've asked IntelliJ to import the wrong one and spend a lot of time on figuring out why my controllers aren't working, only to find out I used wrong `ActionEvent`. Like fellow in this question: [Error resolving "onAction" while loading FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505275/error-resolving-onaction-while-loading-fxml)

So I've begin to wonder if there's an option to foolproof it for the future. Like telling IntelliJ, in which order it should suggest imports, so that all that's under `javafx` would be suggested before `java.awt`. Alternatively display a warning (but preferably an error) each time anything from some package is imported.

Comment: As a workaround, I would write some template text with all the possible JavaFX imports I’ll need, using wildcard `*` syntax. Paste that set of imports at the top of every file. When all done, use IntelliJ’s *Optimize Imports* feature to clean up all those excessive `import` statements.

Comment: Wildcard `*` is a big no-no due to company policy, but writing out those imports is a solution

Comment: IntelliJ's *Optimize Imports* feature eliminates the wildcards, replacing them with specific classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a job for the **Preferences** | **Editor** | **General** | **Auto Import** page's list of exclusions. See [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html#exclude-from-auto-import).